# Считывание чисел из файла

Tags: c++, файлы

У меня есть файл, в котором находятся трехзначные числа. Как мне считать их в массив?

```
while (i < sizeof(sim) && fscanf(f1, "%c", &l) == 1)
{
    sim[i] = l;
    i++;
    count++;
}
```

Данный код считывает символы по одному, и `count` будет равен количеству появлений каждой цифры и пробела по отдельности.

Числа: *201 203 204 207 308 987 789 987 654*. Перед каждым числом стоит по три пробела.

Comment: Непонятно, что вам нужно сделать. Вам нужно подсчитать количество пробелов и цифр, или просто занести числа из файла, допустим, в вектор?

Comment: Надо занести числа из файла в массив, просто выше упомянутая функция читает отдельно 2,0,1,2,0,3....и забивает массив этими числами по отдельности,  а надо чтобы 201,203,... забивались туда

Comment: В таком случае очень важно, на каком языке пишется программа. Например, в C++ это делается вообще одной строчкой, а в C придется повозиться.:)

Comment: Зачем читать побайтно? / Просто поменяйте `%c` на `%d` в формате fscanf (понятно, что l д.б. типа int). Кроме того -- sizeof для определения размера массива (количества элементов в нем) это ошибка (sizeof это размер переменной (массива) в байтах (точнее, в элементах типа char)). Используйте `sizeof(sim) / sizeof(sim[0])`.

Comment: Извините, за глупый вопрос, но я не понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду, просто скажите, что и где надо поставить?

Comment: Просто поменять тип?

Comment: А что такое?sizeof(sim) / sizeof(sim[0])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

template <typename Stream>
bool read_num(Stream &stream, int &number)
{
    char c = 0;
    std::string buf;
    while (true)
    {
        stream.read(&c, 1);
        if (c == ' ' || stream.eof())
        {
            if (!buf.empty())
            {
                number = atoi(buf.c_str());
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buf +=c ;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream digits;
    digits.open("chisla", std::ios_base::in);

    if (!digits.is_open())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (!digits.eof())
    {
        int num;

        if (read_num(digits, num))
            std::cout << num << std::endl; // тут можно складывать в список
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а как реализовать этот код без потоков) я их еще не учил просто)

Comment: тут нет потоков )))) А ты имеешь в виду поток ввода... Ну так учи. У тебя тэг в вопросе C++ стоит, а не СИ.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще вариант с использованием FILE.

```
#include <iostream>

bool read_num(FILE *file, int &number)
{
    char c = 0;
    std::string buf;
    while (true)
    {
        fread(&c, 1, 1, file);
        if (c == ' ' || feof(file))
        {
            if (!buf.empty())
            {
                number = atoi(buf.c_str());
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buf +=c ;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("chisla", "r");

    if (!file)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    while (!feof(file))
    {
        int num;

        if (read_num(file, num))
            std::cout << num << std::endl; // тут можно складывать в список
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: А что, Алексею Мальченко позволено писать столько ответов на один вопрос, сколько его душе заблагорассудится?:)

Comment: Он потом попросил еще вариант, в чем проблема?

Comment: Я считал, что один участник больше одного ответа на заданный вопрос написать не может. И это было бы правильно.  Иначе возникает путаница. Так как ответы надо оценивать вцелом, а не по частям.

Comment: Чувак выбрал тот вариант, который считает правильным в его случае, вот и все.

Comment: Дело в том, что не только он один оценивает ответы. И кроме того, порой если два ответа объединить в один, то видно, например, что вцелом ответ некорректный. Или, напротив, по отдельности каждый ответ некорректный, но если их объединить, то логически выстраивается правильный ответ. Я уверен, что это недоработка администрации сайта.

Comment: Я уверен, что это два разных ответа, а не дополняющие друг друга. Пишите либо по делу, либо напрямую модератору, если что-то не устраивает, пусть рассудит.

Comment: В чем вы уверены, в том другой человек может быть совершенно не уверен. Насколько мне известно, на исходном сайте stackoverflow это делать нельзя. И это правильно. У вас всегда есть возможность отредактировать или дополнить свой ответ.

Comment: Пускай модератор объединит в один ответ тогда. Сейчас, как я понимаю уже поздно это делать, уже дан голос был.

Comment: Вот кстати: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/is-it-ok-to-post-multiple-answers-to-a-question
Разрешается.

Comment: Вы оказались правы, это разрешается делать, хотя лично я против такой практики.